# How can I add arguments in pycurl with DELETE method and python

Tags: python, api, rest, restful-url, pycurl

I have the next code to performance HTTP DELETE METHOD to test a RESTful API, it works fine but now I can add some arguments. I have reading how to do this, but to date I can not solve the problem

Any suggestion.

This is part of the code to do it

```
elif (method == 'DELETE'):
   curl.setopt(pycurl.CUSTOMREQUEST, 'delete')
   if(parameters != None):
      //Here I would like to do it.
```

I read some post that said use CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, but I dont sure about that nor how to use it.
Thanks